# Running my Angular 4 app in production using ng build --prod

Tags: angular, amazon-ec2

I am trying to host my Angular App on an AWS EC2 for my College Project but when i use the ng build --prod command I get an error and don't KNOW how to fix it as I am new to Angular

Here are my versions:

```
Angular CLI: 1.6.7
Node: 6.9.4
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 5.2.3
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router
@angular/cli: 1.6.7
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.0.42
@angular-devkit/core: 0.0.29
@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.0.52
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.1.0
@ngtools/webpack: 1.9.7
@schematics/angular: 0.1.17
typescript: 2.5.3
webpack: 3.10.0
```

and this is the error

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css
Module build failed: BrowserslistError: Unknown browser major
    at error (C:\Users\LSU14\Desktop\myproject\node_modules\postcss-merge-rules\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:37:11)
    at Function.browserslist.checkName (C:\Users\LSU14\Desktop\myproject\node_modules\postcss-merge-rules\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:320:18)
    at Function.select (C:\Users\LSU14\Desktop\myproject\node_modules\postcss-merge-rules\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:438:37)
    at C:\Users\LSU14\Desktop\myproject\node_modules\postcss-merge-rules\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:207:41
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at browserslist (C:\Users\LSU14\Desktop\myproject\node_modules\postcss-merge-rules\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:196:13)
    at C:\Users\LSU14\Desktop\myproject\node_modules\postcss-merge-rules\dist\index.js:261:51
    at LazyResult.run (C:\Users\LSU14\Desktop\myproject\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:277:20)
    at LazyResult.asyncTick (C:\Users\LSU14\Desktop\myproject\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:192:32)
    at LazyResult.asyncTick (C:\Users\LSU14\Desktop\myproject\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:204:22)
    at LazyResult.asyncTick (C:\Users\LSU14\Desktop\myproject\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:204:22)
    at LazyResult.asyncTick (C:\Users\LSU14\Desktop\myproject\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:204:22)
    at LazyResult.asyncTick (C:\Users\LSU14\Desktop\myproject\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:204:22)
    at LazyResult.asyncTick (C:\Users\LSU14\Desktop\myproject\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:204:22)
    at LazyResult.asyncTick (C:\Users\LSU14\Desktop\myproject\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:204:22)
    at LazyResult.asyncTick (C:\Users\LSU14\Desktop\myproject\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:204:22)
 @ multi ./src/styles.css ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css ./node_modules/angular-
```

Comment: Please provide some code.

Comment: which version of bootstrap are you using ??